# How to apply a Date Filter on a list with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, list-view, filter

I have a Date Filter webpart connected to a List on page.

I am setting the default value of the list with JQuery (it sets that value to the next Wednesday).  Here's a [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bmk6hpr2/40/) showing how we are changing the Date Filter.

And it works, the date changes, but the filter doesn't get applied to the list with the new date.

It appears we need to call `SetApplyFiltersToActiveIfPresent();` but adding this function call to our code doesn't do anything.

How can I apply the filter using JS/JQuery?

Comment: Are you using 2013?

Comment: Yes. (need 15 characters.....)

Answer (score 0):

Is there any chance you could try the "Query string Url" filter connected to your list view web part (with appropriate column)? If you need to, you can also pass the date explicitly in the querystring through JS or jQuery.